# Share content on facebook with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, facebook

I'm currently searching for an method to share content on facebook if the user click on a button or when an event is true, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: http://facebooksdk.net/

Comment: I will have a look at this, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [facebook share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/) and supply the URL of the site that you want to share. For example

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={URL_OF_THE_SITE}
```

Now, you have to call this inside your VB.NET application. If you are using the **WebBrowser**, you can call the **`Navigate(String)`** method. Or, if not, you can call the default browser using the **start** command. You will need to call the **Shell** function for this. Example:

```
Shell("start https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={URL_OF_THE_SITE}")
```